# Yii2: Preventing data-method="post" link redirection

Tags: ajax, hyperlink, yii2, xmlhttprequest, http-post

Very straight-forward question: How do we make the following link only submit the POST request, **without** redirecting the browser to */post/delete?id=123* ?

```
<?= \yii\helpers\Html::a('Delete', ['/post/delete','id'=>123], [
    'options'   => [
        'data'  => [
            'method'  => 'post',
            'confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: You can submit a form using ajax without trying to refresh the page, you can also use redirections.
if you try to send a data to somewhere you can use php curl as well.

Answer (score 0):

For example - you have to send the data using AJAX.

jQuery library is shipped with Yii 2 so it is easier to use [Jquery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method.

`data-method="post"` only forces the link to be sent using HTTP POST instead of GET and nothing else.

Comment: That's not true. If you inspect the browser's network monitor it shows 2 requests. First a POST request and a GET request right after, both to the same url.

Comment: Yii transforms links with `data-method="post"` into the forms using JavaScript. For this to work you have to register `yii.js` asset usually through `yii\web\YiiAsset`. Double check if you have got this present - in my browser I can see only one POST request.